# Rewrite all to https with htaccess and Magento

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

We want to redirect every page in Magento to https. We know how to change this in Magento, but we do not know how to do this in our current htaccess? For more information, please see our current htaccess file below, stripped from unnecessary comments.

Current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s+/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

RewriteRule ^home/?$ /? [R=301,L,NC]

# ADD WWW TO NONE WWW FOR BOTH HTTPS AND NONE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#REDIRECT ALL .HTML FILES AND ALL .HTML/ FILES WITH TRAILING SLASH
RewriteRule ^google[0-9a-f]+.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html\/$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# ADD TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# TRAILING SLASH CHECK
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

#CHECK IF REDIRECT POINTS TO A VALID FILE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#REWRITE EVERYTHING ELSE TO INDEX.PHP    
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Solved by adding:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code

```
 RewriteEngine on
```

after

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

And goto admin>SYStem>configuration>General>Web>

```
change all secure url and unsecure to https:
```

ex:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Amit! Everything seems to be working by just change to https:// in Magentos backend/admin pages. When testing, the site itself/Magento is 301:ing all the urls and links? When adding the rewrite rule, I got error from the browser saying "To many redirects". So maybe I don't need to add a rewrite rule at all? You can find the url to the site, in my profile, for testing if you want.

Comment: Update: Found a problem, when accessing a sub directory directly, for example http://www.domain.tld/products/cheezdoodles/ it redirects back to root => https://www.domain.tld/. I'm not using the rewrite rules in htaccess when this is happening. See above. I reverted the changes in the admin pages, and https is disabled right now.

Comment: Solved by adding RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on and RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]